# What can I photograph to get elements in the treasure tab

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Just got the picture mode on my slate, and every category I have to register seems straightforward enough (food, weapons, etc)

Except for the treasure category. Its contains 4 items, and I have no clue what they could be.

So what are they?

PS: Im still early in my first playthrough so if its spoilerish please say so.

Comment: I believe one is for 'Treasure Chest', which requires a picture of any unopened treasure chest. Not sure if each type of chest has it's own picture, however.

Comment: I'll try this tonight, but seems weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to take pictures of the following:

- any Treasure chest
- a regular Ore Node
- a Rare Ore Node
- a Luminous Stone Node